# jmeter error:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I would like to use jmeter(5.4.3) for load testing.
The site I am trying to test is an azure static site.

```
https://XXXXX.web.core.windows.net
```

So I started jmeter and configured the following.

```
In Thread Group,

・Nunumber of threads: 1

・Ramp-up period:1

・Loop Count:1
```

And,

```
In HTTP Request,

・Protocol:https

・Server Name or IP : XXXXX.web.core.windows.net

・HTTP Request
　GET 

・Path:/
```

Then I got this error.

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
```

This is the only configuration I have performed, what am I missing?
I am a beginner and not sure.

Thank you!

These are the error statements.

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to XXXXX.web.core.window.net:443 [XXXXX.web.core.window.net/52.XXX.XX.XXX] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:404)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what's wrong exactly without seeing the full [stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

The first possible reason which comes to my mind is that you're behind a corporate [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) so you need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server).

Additionally you can add the next line to [*system.properties* file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug):

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

and the following line to [*log4j2.xml* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

and inspect [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) and [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) files for any suspicious entries.